# Trying to query based on choice field django

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates

I've been stuck on this all day. I've got a model, Load, within that model it has a choice field with different "statuses".  I am trying to implement some tabbed views in my template. So basically each tab will be responsible for displaying a certain status. I believe that I should be using a queryset within my view get_context_data but I'm just not really understanding how to accomplish this. I've tried a ton of different ways in the view, so i'll just paste the latest attempt.

These query's will be static once they are done so my best thought was to use a model managers for each query, but I couldn't get multiple model managers to work on one model. Here's an example of one.  Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

```
class BookedManager(models.Manager):
    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(BookedManager, self).get_queryset().filter(load_status='Booked')
```

**Models.py**

```
class Load(models.Model):
    load_number = models.IntegerField()
    agent = models.ForeignKey(User,
        limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'Agent'},related_name='Agent', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(User,
        limit_choices_to={'groups__name': 'Customer'},related_name='Customer', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    carrier = models.ForeignKey(Carrier, on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True, null=True)
    pickup_date = models.DateField()
    delivery_date = models.DateField()
    shipper = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='shipper', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    consignee = models.ForeignKey(Location, related_name='consignee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, blank=True)
    po_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pu_number = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pieces = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField()
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    PREBOOK = 'Waiting for Carrier'
    BOOKED = 'Booked'
    CONFIRMED = 'Confirmed Rate'
    PICKED = 'Picked'
    DELIVERED = 'Delivered'
    INVOICED = 'Invoiced'
    PAID = 'Paid'

    LOAD_STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (PREBOOK, 'Waiting for Carrier'),
        (BOOKED, 'Booked'),
        (CONFIRMED, 'Signed Rate Confirmation'),
        (PICKED, 'Picked Up'),
        (DELIVERED, 'Delivered'),
        (INVOICED, 'Invoiced'),
        (PAID, 'Paid'),
    )
    load_status = models.CharField(max_length=30, choices=LOAD_STATUS_CHOICES, default=PREBOOK)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        LoadUpdateHistory.objects.create(your_model=self, updated=timezone.now())

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('loads:detail',kwargs={'pk':self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.load_number)
```

**views.py**

```
class LoadListView(ListView):
    model = Load
    context_object_name = 'loads'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoadListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['booked'] = Load.objects.filter(load_status__contains='booked')
        return context
```

**Template**

```
{% for load in loads %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="{% url 'loads:detail' pk=load.pk%}">{{load.load_number}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{load.agent}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.customer.company_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.carrier}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pickup_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.delivery_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.shipper}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.consignee}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.po_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pu_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                      <a href="{% url 'loads:delete' pk=load.pk%}">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
```

**Update 1/21/17**

**Views.py**

```
class LoadListView(ListView):
    model = Load
    context_object_name = 'loads'

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoadListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        """
        This was probably my biggest mistake, I kept trying to query from 
        Load.load_status, load_status doesn't have a choice, it holds a variable 
        which then holds a status.
        which i'm assuming is why i can't query off of the object load_status.

        This new Loop says for the first choice in Load.LOAD_STATUS_CHOICES.
        I'm not really understanding why we are selecting the first choice here.
        """
        statuses = (choice[0] for choice in Load.LOAD_STATUS_CHOICES)

        """
        Then we pass in loads_by_status into the template it filters the load_status
        object and gets the status in statuses.
        """
        context['loads_by_status'] = {
            status: Load.objects.filter(load_status=status) for status in statuses
        }
        return context
```

My result in adding this code is that the template is not returning anything so I must be calling the data wrong in the template.

**Template**

```
<div>

  <!-- Nav tabs -->
  <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist" id='myTab'>
    <li role="presentation" class="active"><a href="#allLoads" aria-controls="allLoads" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">All Loads</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#waitingForCarrier" aria-controls="waitingForCarrier" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Waiting For Carrier</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#booked" aria-controls="booked" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Booked</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#confirmed" aria-controls="confirmed" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Confirmed</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#picked" aria-controls="picked" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Picked</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#delivered" aria-controls="delivered" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Delivered</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#invoiced" aria-controls="invoiced" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Invoiced</a></li>
    <li role="presentation"><a href="#paid" aria-controls="paid" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Paid</a></li>
  </ul>

  <!-- Tab panes -->
  <div class="tab-content">
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade in active" id="allLoads">
      <h1>All Loads</h1>
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
          width="100%">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Load Number</th>
                      <th>Load Status</th>
                      <th>Agent</th>
                      <th>Customer</th>
                      <th>Carrier</th>
                      <th>Pickup Date</th>
                      <th>Delivery Date</th>
                      <th>Shipper</th>
                      <th>Consignee</th>
                      <th>PO Number</th>
                      <th>PU Number</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Load Number</th>
                    <th>Load Status</th>
                    <th>Agent</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Carrier</th>
                    <th>Pickup Date</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Shipper</th>
                    <th>Consignee</th>
                    <th>PO Number</th>
                    <th>PU Number</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                {% for load in loads %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">{{load.load_number}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{load.load_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.agent}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.customer.company_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.carrier}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pickup_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.delivery_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.shipper}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.consignee}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.po_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pu_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="waitingForCarrier">
      <h1>Waiting For Carrier</h1>
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
          width="100%">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Load Number</th>
                      <th>Load Status</th>
                      <th>Agent</th>
                      <th>Customer</th>
                      <th>Carrier</th>
                      <th>Pickup Date</th>
                      <th>Delivery Date</th>
                      <th>Shipper</th>
                      <th>Consignee</th>
                      <th>PO Number</th>
                      <th>PU Number</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Load Number</th>
                    <th>Load Status</th>
                    <th>Agent</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Carrier</th>
                    <th>Pickup Date</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Shipper</th>
                    <th>Consignee</th>
                    <th>PO Number</th>
                    <th>PU Number</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                {% for status, load in loads_by_status.items %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">{{load.load_number}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{load.load_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.agent}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.customer.company_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.carrier}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pickup_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.delivery_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.shipper}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.consignee}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.po_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pu_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
    <div role="tabpanel" class="tab-pane fade" id="booked">
      <h1>Booked</h1>
      <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" cellspacing="0"
          width="100%">
              <thead>
                  <tr>
                      <th>Load Number</th>
                      <th>Load Status</th>
                      <th>Agent</th>
                      <th>Customer</th>
                      <th>Carrier</th>
                      <th>Pickup Date</th>
                      <th>Delivery Date</th>
                      <th>Shipper</th>
                      <th>Consignee</th>
                      <th>PO Number</th>
                      <th>PU Number</th>
                      <th>Date Created</th>
                      <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </thead>
              <tfoot>
                  <tr>
                    <th>Load Number</th>
                    <th>Load Status</th>
                    <th>Agent</th>
                    <th>Customer</th>
                    <th>Carrier</th>
                    <th>Pickup Date</th>
                    <th>Delivery Date</th>
                    <th>Shipper</th>
                    <th>Consignee</th>
                    <th>PO Number</th>
                    <th>PU Number</th>
                    <th>Date Created</th>
                    <th>Action</th>
                  </tr>
              </tfoot>
              <tbody>
                {% for status, load in loads_by_status.items %}
                <tr>
                    <td><a href="#">{{load.load_number}}</a></td>
                    <td>{{load.load_status}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.agent}}</td>
                    <td>{{user.customer.company_name}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.carrier}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pickup_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.delivery_date}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.shipper}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.consignee}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.po_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.pu_number}}</td>
                    <td>{{load.date_created}}</td>
                    <td>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-warning" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                      <a href="#">
                        <button class="btn btn-danger" type="button">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> </button>
                      </a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                {% endfor %}
              </tbody>
          </table>
    </div>
```

Comment: Where's the code for your tabs?

Comment: I couldn't paste the whole template but I showed the first tab which should just display all loads. Then the "booked tab" which should show booked loads

Comment: Thanks, Kris, please see blow, where I've updated the template for @dukebody.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need a custom model manager for those queries at all. You can accomplish this sending the loads grouped by status to the template:

```
class LoadListView(ListView):
    # ...
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(LoadListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        statuses = (choice[0] for choice in Load.LOAD_STATUS_CHOICES)
        context['loads_by_status'] = {
            status: Load.objects.filter(load_status=status) for status in statuses
        }
        return context
```

Template:

```
{% for status, loads in loads_by_status.items %}
<h4>Status: {{ status }}</h4>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Load number</th>
            ...
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    {# remember, loads is a queryset at this point #}
    {% for load in loads %}
        <tr>
            <td>{{ load.load_number }}</td>
            ...
        </tr>
     {% endfor %}
     </tbody>
</table>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: This is probably the most advanced query I've worked with so I apologize if I'm not understanding this right but my template now doesn't show any of the loads. So I must have something wrong with the new context and template. If you wouldn't mind viewing my code above. I added some comments to help myself try and understand this better.

Comment: I also assume doing something like this in the template is bad code:

{% if load.load_status == "Confirmed Rate" %}

{% endif %}

Comment: @dukebody:  i think you misunderstood your template. I'll try to adjust.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo in my previous template snippet, wrote `{{loads.load_number}}` instead of `{{load.load_number}}`. Try now.

Comment: @2ps huge help guys!! I've got some HTML to adjust but this has put me on the right track!